# Python 3 program finding smallest number between 4 inputs

Tags: python

I am learning Python and got stuck on a task with creating program that will find smallest number of 4 using only `if` and `else`. No `elif`, no `min`, no `list` etc, only base if and else

I dont really have any ideas, I only made 2 programs which use `elif`, but they dont work too:

```
x=int (input())
b=int (input())
c=int (input())
d=int (input())
if x<b and  x<c and x<d:
    print (x)
elif b<x and b<c and b<d:
    print (b)
elif c<x and c<b and c<d:
    print (c)
else: print (d)
```

```
File "c:\Python\r.py", line 1, in <module>
x=int (input())
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10
```

and

```
a=int (input())
b=int (input())
c=int (input())
d=int (input())
n1=int
n2=int
if a<b:
    a=n1
else: b=n1
if c<d:
    c=n2
else: d=n2
n1=int
n2=int
if n1<n2:
    print (n1)
else: print (n2)
```

```
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'type' and 'type'
```

Comment: What did you try to input in your first program? Did you just press return?

Comment: Your first one works fine as long as you enter a number in each prompt. Your second is unlikely to throw that error since you aren't using `<=` anywhere in your code. I'm guessing though it's originating from `n1=int`... whatever that is supposed to be doing (it's nonsense). I think you are trying to initialize a variable like `n1=None`? And then set the variable with `b=n1`, which should be `n1=b`.

Comment: 1- is not a [mre] if you input nonesense like "hello", of course it's going to fail. 2- what would `int < int` mean in `n1<n2`?

Comment: The reason you're getting an error in your second example is because you have, for example, `n1=int` as opposed to `n1=int()` (note the parentheses in the second case). In the first case, you're setting n1 equal to the _class_ `int`, whereas in the second, you're calling `int`'s constructor, and thereby setting `n1` to 0.

If you get rid of the second assignment of `n1=int` and `n2=int` and fix the parentheses issue, then as written your second program should work correctly

Comment: quamranai tried to return several integers
JNevill could you elaborate about numbers in promts?
Julien about 2nd one, i wanted to compare both of them to pick smallest number

sorry idk how to use stackoverflow properly

Comment: What are you trying to do with `n1 = int`? What integer are you trying to assign to `n1`?

Comment: Can you use nested `if` statements? That would be the way to organize this.

Comment: @Pacopenguin i removed it,now it says  
> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10
 instead of TypeError

Comment: @Barmar yes, i can use nested `if` statements, i was trying to assign smallest number of `a` and `b` to `n1`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. I'm glad you got a solution, but Stack Overflow is a Q&A site but there's no question here, so this post has been closed. Please read [How to ask and answer homework questions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341). See also [ask] in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using nested `if` statements to test all the possibilities.

```
n1 = int(input())
n2 = int(input())
n3 = int(input())
n4 = int(input())

if n1 < n2:
    if n1 < n3:
        if n1 < n4:
            print(n1)
        else:
            print(n4)
    else:
        if n3 < n4:
            print(n3)
        else:
            print(n4)
else:
    if n2 < n3:
        if n2 < n4:
            print(n2)
        else:
            print(n4)
    else:
        if n3 < n4:
            print(n3)
        else:
            print(n4)
```

Comment: Sorry, I cant use `return` and `lowest`. Any other ways to do it?

Comment: You can take the logic out of the function and use `print()` instead of `return`. This was just easier for testing.